# Print coordinates (Astropy)

Tags: python, astropy

From the Astropy documentation, this example is given:

```
c = SkyCoord('00h42m30s', '+41d12m00s')
```

when `print(c)` is given you get

`<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg (10.625, 41.2)>`

but what if I want to have an output like "the right ascension is 10.625 and the declination is 41.2"?

My initial thought was that I could just use c[0] and c[1] but it seems that it's not indexable, any tips?

Comment: If 41d is 41.2 how can you do 42m is 10.625, i think it is 1. something...

Comment: I just used the example in the documentation. The values arent important cause that wasnt my question though. @BiswajitPaloi

Comment: Perhaps the `to_string()` method might be more helpful than what you get when you `print`

Comment: Okay so i have `data = c.to_string()` right now and i when i print it i only get them up to 3 decimals... data[0] also doesnt work here @JohnColeman

Comment: Maybe try `c.to_table()` and figure out how to extract the numbers from that table object.

Comment: Doesnt work... Ive been stuck for hours now @JohnColeman

Comment: It is a kludge if it works, but maybe try `re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+',str(c))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Did you try

```py
>>> c = SkyCoord('00h42m30s', '+41d12m00s')
>>> print(f'the right ascention is {c.ra.value:0.3f} and the declination is {c.dec.value:0.2f}')
the right ascention is 10.625 and the declination is 41.20
```